# Arbitrarily large sequence of numbers with a property

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

We say that a positive integer is good if it has an even number of prime factors. Does there exist an arbitrarily large sequence of consecutive good numbers?

In fact, this problem came from another one: Show that there exists an infinite set $S$ of positive integers such that the sum of any two distinct elements of S has an even number of distinct prime factors.

If the first statement about long sequences of good numbers is true, then I can finish the second problem as follows: Choose $s_{1}\in \mathbb{N}$ randomly. Then, we will define the increasing sequence $s_{n}$ inductively. Take a sequence of $s_{n-1}+1$ consecutive good numbers. If $a$ is the smallest one in this sequence, take $s_{n}=a$. Then set $S=\{s_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$.

Comment: Is 12 good? (That is, are you taking into account multiplicity of prime factors?)

Comment: @MichaelLugo We must take them into account because $4$ consecutive numbers force a number divisible by $4$

Comment: @Peter not necessarily.  You'd be right if the original question asked for arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive *bad* numbers.

Comment: @Peter it should affect the answer, because "good" and "bad" numbers are different under the different definitions.  But actually my original comment doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Heuristically, which numbers are "good" is essentially coin-flipping, and we should expect arbitrarily long runs of heads in a sequence of coin flips.  But these sort of things are notoriously hard to prove.

Comment: Starting with $$6762278$$ , we can create a run with $23$ numbers (assuming that distinct prime factors are meant)

Comment: And starting with $167577879$ gives a run of $26$ numbers.

Comment: @MichaelLugo 12 is a good number. That is, the multiplicity is not important

Comment: Even if we consider multiplicity, sequences longer than $20$ are possible. Starting with $68780189$ gives a $28$-run in this case.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Maybe, we can have arbitary long sequences in both cases.

Comment: @Rhcpy99 Would you be content with a very long run ? A proof that we can have an arbitary long sequence is probably out of reach.

Comment: Peter's tests are roughly in line with my coin-flipping heuristic (that is, that we should have a run of length $n$ by around $2^n$).

Comment: I just want to solve the original problem. If this strstegy is hard to proof, I will find another one.

Comment: You're asking if the Liouville function has arbitrarily long runs of $1$s. Some searching suggests that such questions are open. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78623/fluctuations-of-liouville-function

Comment: @Rhcpy99 I think that the original problem is also very hard.

Comment: The original question has a nice non-constructive proof using Ramsey's theorem, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7527/find-an-infinite-set-of-positive-integers-such-that-the-sum-of-any-two-distinct